# Tiny amount of USDT returns during swap

Tags: 0x

This [transaction](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x4a0f01a0f12637ebd98feec03efe5dbaf121cff651a1dc9598a74595ddbb4ea4) is swapped USDT -> USDC. Also in this tx, I see a transfer of 0.000002 USDT to the user's address. The question is what this transfer means and why it happens?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably a rounding leftover.

USDC uses 6 decimal point precision, so 0.000002 would be a reasonable division leftover.